# Hidden Input Form Group (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a hidden input within a form group on Bootstrap 4, the problem I am having is that the `form-group`'s margin-bottom is still there making the form have a bit of extra padding at the bottom, making the hidden inputs quite noticeable. I know I can just remove the margin on form-group, but I'm utilizing it on the visible fields.

> Is there any way to remove the margin if an input within the form
>   group is hidden?

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <input type="hidden" readonly="" name="entry" value="111">
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a display=none to the div that surrounds the input tag.
Either add an inline style (not good) or create a class with the display property and add it to the div (that has the form-group class).